# when condition met, carry to end of group for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Ok so I am writing some code that will when a certain - value is met, its to continue to print 0 until the end of the group.

I wrote some code, its easier to show with an example:

```
# STop loss Script example

    # Trade signal and dollar gain loss
    sig <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
    dollar <- c(0,0,0,0,100,150,190,-1000,100,100,100,0,0,0,100,100,100,0)
    df <- data.frame(sig,dollar)

    # initialize total column
    df$total = 0
    i=1
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
      if (df$sig[i] == 1 ) {
        df$total[i] = df$dollar[i] + df$total[i-1]  # cum sum each dollar
    } else if (df$sig[i] == 0) {
      df$total[i] = 0 }
    }


    # Code for stop loss 
    # Initialize stop signal column 
    df$stop <- 0
    stop = -500
    i = 1
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
      if (df$sig[i] == 1 & df$total[i] > stop) { 
        df$stop[i] = 1 } 
      }
```

now i can explain the out put:

```
   sig dollar total stop
1    0      0     0    0
2    0      0     0    0
3    0      0     0    0
4    0      0     0    0
5    1    100   100    1
6    1    150   250    1
7    1    190   440    1
8    1  -1000  -560    0
9    1    100  -460    1
10   1    100  -360    1
11   1    100  -260    1
12   0      0     0    0
13   0      0     0    0
14   0      0     0    0
15   1    100   100    1
16   1    100   200    1
17   1    100   300    1
18   0      0     0    0
```

the code for stop loss, when i met a df$total value <-500 then i print 0 instead of 1. Straight forward. However, because this condition is met, so long as df$sig == 1, i wish to continue to make df$total == 0. Then for the next df$sig == 1 (maybe group 2) ion line 15, repeat the process all over again.

The desired output might help too

```
> df
   sig dollar total stop
1    0      0     0    0
2    0      0     0    0
3    0      0     0    0
4    0      0     0    0
5    1    100   100    1
6    1    150   250    1
7    1    190   440    1
8    1  -1000  -560    0
9    1    100  -460    0
10   1    100  -360    0
11   1    100  -260    0
12   0      0     0    0
13   0      0     0    0
14   0      0     0    0
15   1    100   100    1
16   1    100   200    1
17   1    100   300    1
18   0      0     0    0
```

I have tried this code so far:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
  if (df$sig[i] == 1 & df$total[i] > stop) { 
    df$stop[i] = 1 } 
  else if (df$total[i-1] == 0) {
    df$stop[i] = 0 }
  }
```

idea was that if the df$stop 0 from 1 iteration ago was 0 then the next d$stop would be 0. This is problematic, because i have leading 0 until the first group of df$sig = 1 is met... So as I have that leading 0, df$stop = 0 and it runs 0 through all iterations.

so i then thought about turning all 0 to NA so the code wouldnt trigger on the leading 0's. That threw an error. Anyone see a convenient solution?

Comment: Maybe I can make all 0 NA, then another help column if Sig = 1 then make NA 0,then run tne code i wrote, should work... Unless there is a better way using break or next

Answer (score 1):

You can change the last part for this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
  if (df$sig[i] == 1 & df$total[i] > stop) { 
    df$stop[i] = 1
    if (i > 1) {
      if (df$sig[i - 1] == 1 & df$stop[i - 1] == 0) {
        df$stop[i] = 0
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

It results in:

```
 sig dollar total stop
1    0      0     0    0
2    0      0     0    0
3    0      0     0    0
4    0      0     0    0
5    1    100   100    1
6    1    150   250    1
7    1    190   440    1
8    1  -1000  -560    0
9    1    100  -460    0
10   1    100  -360    0
11   1    100  -260    0
12   0      0     0    0
13   0      0     0    0
14   0      0     0    0
15   1    100   100    1
16   1    100   200    1
17   1    100   300    1
18   0      0     0    0
```

Comment: Great i will check when I get back to my screen, looks like I was close!